# How to check if a razor view exists, but in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I know that we can use this code to see if a view is already defined or not:

```
ViewEngine.FindView(ViewContext, $"NameOfPartialView", isMainPage: false).Success
```

But I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, and I'm mixing it with simple razor views.
This line returns false, while view is there.

My project hierarchy is like this:

- Pages

  - Gallery

    - List.cshtml

      - List.cshtml.cs
    - Augmenter.cshtml

As you can see, `List.cshtml` is a razor page. It has code behind. But `Augmenter.cshtml` is a simple razor view, without code behind.

And inside `List.cshtml` I want to check if `Augmenter.cshtml` exist or not.

This code didn't work for me. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo which can work in my project:

structure:

[image]

List.cshtml(You need to make sure if the `viewName` in `FindView` is correct,you can only pass viewname without .cshtml to it):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
@if (Engine.FindView(ViewContext, "Augmenter", isMainPage: false).Success)
{
    <p>exist</p>
}
```

result:
[image]